# Create an String dynamically based on parameters

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm parametrizing a query in Scala.

I have an array of strings with column names named `colNames`.

I want to create an string where for each name of the string the output is `A.colName = B.colName` and then join all the items in the array putting an " AND " string between each item.

Example of input

```
val colNames = Array("colName1","colName2")
val table1 = "A"
val table2 = "B"
```

Example of the desired output

```
"A.colName1 = B.colName1 AND A.colName2 = B.colName2"
```

In a non FP language I would do that with a for loop, but I don't know how to do it in Scala in a functional way.

Comment: Are you using raw JDBC driver? How do you want to pair `"A"` with `"colName1"` and `"B"` with `"colName2"`?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I am passingg the raw query to the snowflake spark llibrary. A and B are the tables and i want to use them in a where condition where the columnName are equals

Comment: Then @Dogbert's answer should do the trick. (I wouldn't use infix notation though).

Comment: Whereever this piece of query ends up: make sure that the content of `colNames` is not controlled by the users, otherwise you'll quickly get requests along the lines of `colNames = Array("colName1", "colName2 AND sendAllTehCoinzTo('BobbyTables') = 'success'")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Array.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):CC%5BB%5D) and [`mkString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Array.html#mkString(sep:String):String) methods on Array:

```scala
scala> colNames map { colName => s"${table1}.${colName} = ${table2}.${colName}" } mkString " AND "
val res0: String = A.colName1 = B.colName1 AND A.colName2 = B.colName2
```